# How to prove that the sequence $(-1)^{n+1} \times \frac {n}{n+1} $ diverges?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation

I actually already have proof but I don't understand it, this proof is from the books "Mathematical Proof, A Transition to Advanced Mathematics".

Here it is : [The proof from the book.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjpJI.png)

First why does  $\epsilon = 1/2$ ? And why after $\epsilon = L/2 $ ?

I don't understand how to choose epsilon in fact when you read evidence like that it seems to fall from the sky.

Is it that each time we want to prove a divergence we have to separate in three cases $L = 0$, $L< 0$ and $L >0$?

I would really like to understand calculus in more depth so I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Take a look at how I fixed your title. If you want more than one character to be in the superscript, you have to use braces. Otherwise, only one character will be in the superscript. Compare `x^(x + 1)` $x^(x + 1)$ with `x^{x + 1}` $x^{x + 1}$

Comment: This author assumes the limit exists. By definition, since the limit exists you can choose whatever epsilon you like to use later in the proof. The author chooses three different epsilons depending on which case they are in for L

Comment: Thank you, i didn't knew this.

Comment: But the epsilon works perfectly each time, you said that if i choose epsilon = L/2 or epsilon = 49 it doesn't matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember what it means for a sequence to converge:
$(\forall \epsilon>0) (\exists N\in\mathbb N)( \forall n\geq N) |a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

The logical negation is $(\exists \epsilon>0) (\forall N\in\mathbb N)( \exists n\geq N) |a_n-L|\geq \epsilon$.

That is, to show a sequence does not converge to a proposed limit, it suffices to find *some* $\epsilon$, and *some* $n$ (no matter how large a lower bound for $n$ you choose) s.t. the sequence is *not* within $\epsilon$ of the proposed limit. Showing this for *any* proposed limit shows the sequence is *divergent*.

Thus, the proof chooses particular $\epsilon$ and particular $n$ to work for each case considered.  Choosing these requires some intuition or calculations.  We know the sequence starts out at $1/2$ ($n=1$) and alternates signs between positive (odd $n$) and negative (even $n$) whilst increasing in absolute value, oscillating between close to $+1$ and $-1$ in the long run. Thus,

1. To show it does not converge to $0$, it suffices to choose $\epsilon=1/2$ since we know it is never within $1/2$ away from $0$.
2. To show it does not converge to a positive limit, it suffices to choose $\epsilon$ equal to half the limit size since it would have to be positive to be within $\epsilon$ of the limit, but we know this is not true at even $n$.
3. To show it does not converge to a negative limit, it suffices to choose $\epsilon$ equal to half the limit size since it would have to be negative to be within $\epsilon$ of the limit, but we know this is not true at odd $n$.

Answer (score 0):

> First, why does $\epsilon = 1/2$?

In fact, there's no particular need to pick $\epsilon = 1/2$. You could pick any $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ and make the proof work.

How did we know that we would need some $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$? Let's consider the quantity $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |(-1)^{n + 1} \frac{n}{n + 1}| = 1$. So we see that for odd $n$, we see that $(-1)^{n + 1} \frac{n}{n + 1}$ goes to 1, while for even $n$, the quantity goes to $-1$. So it should eventually be the case that $(-1)^{n + 1} \frac{n}{n + 1} \notin (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$.

> Is it the case that each time we want to prove a divergence we have to separate in three cases

No. There are many ways to prove that a sequence does not converge.

In fact, this isn't even the simplest method to prove divergence in this case. Consider the following fact:

> Theorem: Suppose $b$ is a subsequence of $a$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$. Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = L$.

In particular, we have the following corollary:

> Corollary: If we have two subsequences $b, c$ of $a$, and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n \neq \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_n$, then $a$ diverges.

So we can use my observation about the even limit and the odd limit to get that the sequence diverges.

Comment: Thanks, i understood better now but why epsilon must be in (0,1) ? If there is convergence so it must be true for every positive epsilon right ?

Comment: Convergence means a property holds for all $\epsilon$. To disprove convergence, we need only show the property fails for one $\epsilon$. To make this proof work, we can pick any particular $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, not just $\epsilon = 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Differently from the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, you can prove such sequence diverges because it has two subsequences that converge to different values. As we know, in metric spaces, if a sequence converges, then every subsequence must converge to the same value. If we define:
\begin{align*}
a_{n} = (-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{n+1}
\end{align*}
then $a_{2k}$ converges to $-1$ and $a_{2k+1}$ converges to $1$. Hence we conclude that such sequence diverges.

Hopefully this helps!